# How does one, from a list of objects, group and collect just specific values which are explicitly referred to, each by its key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, key-value

I have a data structure like

```
const dd = [{
  keyone: "test",
  two: "you",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "youuuu",
  two: "ttt",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "operation",
  two: "test",
  three: 'op',
}];
```

And I am wanting to be able to pull out keyone and two into an object like the following

```
const obj = { keyone: ['test', 'youuuu', 'operation'], two: ['you', 'ttt', 'test']}
```

I've achieved this using two maps and combining them but I would like to use only one loop if possible.

EDIT:

I am currently using destructuring to extract values:

```
const mapOne = dd.map(({ keyone }) => keyone);
const mapTwo = dd.map(({ two }) => two);
const test = {
  keyone: mapOne,
  two: mapTwo,
};
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @NathanLeadill ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of keys and group the values together.

```js
const
    data = [{ keyone: "test", two: "you", three: 'op' }, { keyone: "youuuu", two: "ttt", three: 'op' }, { keyone: "operation", two: "test", three: 'op' }],
    keys = ['keyone', 'two'],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach(k => (r[k] ??= []).push(o[k]));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: you are right, please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

A generically implemented, thus re-usable and configurable function, which does exactly what the OP did ask for, would be close to the next provided example code ...

```js
function groupAndCollectSpecifcEntriesOnly(collector, item) {
  const { keyList, result } = collector;

  keyList.forEach(key => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

      (result[key] ??= []).push(item[key])
    }
  });
  return collector;
}

const sampleData = [{
  keyone: "test",
  two: "you",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "youuuu",
  two: "ttt",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "operation",
  two: "test",
  three: 'op',
}];

console.log(
  sampleData.reduce(groupAndCollectSpecifcEntriesOnly, {

    keyList: ['keyone', 'two'],
    result: {},

  }).result
);
console.log(
  sampleData.reduce(groupAndCollectSpecifcEntriesOnly, {

    keyList: ['three', 'keyone'],
    result: {},

  }).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: suggestion: `groupAndCollectSpecifcEntriesOnly` can be a function that has the `reduce` logic so that `keyList` can be passed as an argument instead of making it a part of the accumulator.

Comment: @RameshReddy ... A single function like suggested which has to be invoked directly (not capable of being used as callback function) would make _re-usable **and** e.g. configurable reducers_ impossible as much as it prevents chained standard operations/methods on data-structures. On the other hand an initially passed accumulator/collector object can be anything. There is no rule/law which prevents its usage as configurable collector object.

Comment: makes sense but "On the other hand an initially passed accumulator/collector object can be anything" `groupAndCollectSpecifcEntriesOnly` expects the accumulator to be an object that has `keyList`, `result`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const dd = [
{
  keyone: "test",
  two: "you",
  three: 'op'
},
{
  keyone: "youuuu",
  two: "ttt",
  three: 'op'
},
{
  keyone: "operation",
  two: "test",
  three: 'op'
}];
const result = dd.reduce((prev, acc, arr ) => {
       if (acc['keyone']) { prev['keyone'].push(acc['keyone']) } 
       if (acc['two']) { prev['two'].push(acc['two']) }
       return prev;
}, {keyone: [], two: []});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use [object destructuring](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-object-destructuring/) to extract 'keyone' and 'two' from the object `data` and `push` them into an object of arrays, within the same `map` loop)
Don't forget to check for undefined. My code here assumes you don't want zeros or empty strings.

```js
const data = 
  [{ keyone: "test", two: "you", three: 'op' }, 
  { keyone: "youuuu", two: "ttt", three: 'op' }, 
  { keyone: "operation", two: "test", three: 'op' }];

   // declare an object 'result' with two keys, 
   // each with an array as it's property:
const result = { keyone:[], two:[] }
   // each array el of data is an object:
   // which can be destructured with {}
data.map(({ keyone, two }) => {
   if ( keyone )
      result.keyone.push( keyone );
   if ( two )
      result.two.push( two )
})

console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by one iteration on your array using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and on every iteration, iterating over your object by [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const data = [ { keyone: "test", two: "you", three: 'op' }, { keyone: "youuuu", two: "ttt", three: 'op' }, { keyone: "operation", two: "test", three: 'op' }];
const targetKeys = ['keyone', 'two']

const result = data.reduce((acc, obj)=> {
  targetKeys.forEach(k => { (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(obj[k]) });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There are two loops one for reduce and another forEach inside. How can this be one iteration, isn't it  O(n2)?

Comment: Also this pulls all keys instead of just keyone and two

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara assuming n is the number of elements, this is not O(n^2) because `Object.keys(obj)` doesn't have n keys

Comment: I mean O(n*m) if there are variable keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and maybe my solution is not the best. I created a function, where you can add as an optional parameter the amount of keys you want to getter the information from. I asumed that you don't know the name of the keys.

```js
const dd = [{
  keyone: "test",
  two: "you",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "youuuu",
  two: "ttt",
  three: 'op',
}, {
  keyone: "operation",
  two: "test",
  three: 'op',
}];

getterInformation(dd);

function getterInformation(object, keyCount = Object.keys(object).length) {
  let objectWithDesiredKey = {};

  for (let index = 0; index < keyCount; index++) {
    objectWithDesiredKey[`${Object.keys(object[0])[index]}`] = [];
  }

  object.forEach((items) => {
    for (const key in items) {
      if (key in objectWithDesiredKey) {
        objectWithDesiredKey[key].push(items[key]);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(objectWithDesiredKey);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I did not use jQuery so idk what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const dd = [{
        keyone: "test",
        two: "you",
        three: 'op'
    },
    {
        keyone: "youuuu",
        two: "ttt",
        three: 'op'
    },
    {
        keyone: "operation",
        two: "test",
        three: 'op'
    }
];

const pullOut = (...keys) => {
    return keys.map(key => {
        const val = dd.reduce((pV, cV, cI) => {
            pV.push(cV[key]);
            return pV;
        }, []);
        return {
            [key]: val
        };
    }).reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {});
};

console.log(pullOut('keyone', 'two'));
```

Comment: OP doesn't want an array

Comment: @RameshReddy Thanks for the reminder, I ignored this when I code , have re-edited the answer